# Are the teeth of this machine iron or steel?

Tags: plastic

I want to buy or have such a machine built, but the teeth must be steel.

**[Shredding Hard and Soft Things with Plastic Crushing Machine][1]**

https://youtu.be/z1-wj7Go8R0

Comment: Hi Lonelyman40, why exactly are you asking this? And if the teeth must be steel, why do you need this information? The lack of clarity also makes your post look like spam.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It does not appear to be related to hand-made arts and crafts

Comment: I want to buy this machine, I think you misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

The word "iron" (referring to the material / substance) has two meanings:

- literally: the pure substance, found in Mendeleev's table as Fe;
- colloquially: (almost) any alloy that contains mostly iron.

In reality, everything that is called "iron" is either some steel, or some cast iron. I am not a specialist, so I cannot provide too many details.

---

> Are the teeth of this machine iron or steel?

The way you ask, the only answer can be: it is steel. It cannot be cast iron, because it is brittle. Special steels, on other hand, can be very tough and do that kind of job without problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can find plans for making various shredding machines by using the terms "metal shredding machine plans" which will also present a number of plans for similar machines for shredding plastic.

The difference would be the thickness of the shredding wheels and especially the shape of the teeth and the power of the motor. There were too many returns from my search to present a list in this post.

Additionally, the plans are likely to provide resources for having the shredding wheels created. There are a number of online resources which require that you send a drawing in approved form and specifications for the material. For an appropriate cost, you will receive the item from that drawing.

If you live near an industrial area, you may be able to locate someone with a waterjet cutter or a plasma jet cutter who can create the wheels, but the drawing will still be required. It's likely that accurate holes are to be drilled into the center of the wheel, something you cannot expect to receive from a waterjet or plasma jet service. The online service will have the ability to provide accurate and precise hole drilling.

Answer (score 2):

They are hardened tool steel ; per @ virolino , essentially nothing today is "iron" although many things are made of various cast irons.There are 50 different tool steel that could be used depending on what is shredded and the expected life . The practical answer is ; whatever the manufacturer uses. If you had two manufacturers offering two different alloys , that is a different question.